# Best way to process huge Json Http Request

Tags: java, json, playframework, gson

How to efficiently process a lot of Json requests. Currently I use Gson to map the Json request to an object, which creates a lot of objects in the process. Is this the right way ? or should I just use the request that I receive in play `request().body().asJson()` and use it directly somehow.

I am getting thousands of requests per second. So I need to know if there is some other way to handle this. Instead of creating thousands of objects in memory and GC kicking in every now and then.

Comment: If you have a limited set of requests, you could use some cache (e.g. Ehcache) to speed up the response.

Comment: I will be using a cache in my overall design. But the request rate is too high. So if my heap can handle the object creation (short lived). I will be more then happy rather then using Cache to save these requests. (I already have my responses in cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The garbage collectors from Java 7 and onwards are [very good at handling many **short-lived** objects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149563/88986) in a short period. So, you are okay if these objects get processed and deferenced very quickly; make sure you are doing that.

Apart from that, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Are you actually having a problem? A performance bottleneck? Are transactions unresponsive?

If your answer to all of these questions is "no", then don't worry about it. If you answer is "yes", then please (in a different question) post more details about **exactly what performance problems you're seeing** and how to reproduce them with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and we can help you try to solve that specific problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely follow your advice.